# What is this vehicle during the filming of the bus flip in Terminator Genisys

Tags: production, film-techniques, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

[In this "behind the scenes" footage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jscW05NSg7M), which shows how the bus flip was done, at 0:52 there is a strange vehicle that comes up alongside the bus:

[image]

What is this?  It appears to be a normal car enclosed inside a metal cage.  I am guessing the reason for the slanted front is to prevent any of the  cables (which were used to flip the bus) from catching the front of the car.

But I don't understand its purpose.  If it were a camera car, then I would expect the top to be open so cameras could be mounted.  Also, I don't remember any side shots this close in the film. (There are some side shots, but they are perhaps 100' away, on the other side of the bridge railing.)

So what is the purpose of this car?

BTW when I saw the movie, I had no idea this was a practical stunt.  I just assumed it was CGI.

Comment: If I had to guess, i'd say that it was a camera pursuit vehicle, the rails on the front are to mount cameras on.

Comment: @Richard Then why aren't there any cameras?

Comment: I saw Terminator Genesys and there is no such scene. The bus flip scene is shown from exterior wide angle cameras from what I remember. From the looks of the vehicle it looks like crew vehicle used to provide moving ramp to other vehicle. The screenshot looks from making or production video of the movie.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri I grabbed the screenshot from the video clip I linked to.  I agree, I don't remember any shots in either the trailers or the final movie that were that close to the bus, except for the camera mounted underneath the bus itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on my earlier comment, if I had to guess, I'd say that it was a **camera pursuit vehicle.** The rails on the front are presumably to mount cameras onto.

If you zoom in a little, you can see (from earlier in the "making of" video) that there's a ball-shaped camera mounted *inside* the frame on the front.

[image]

Comment: There are at least two separate  cars -- the one you show as your first sill, with the cameras at the back, and the one I am referring to.  One runs ahead of the bus, and the other runs alongside it.